# Вылезает текст за рамки таблицы

Tags: html, разметка

Здравствуйте! Появилась неприятная штука: если пользователь вводит непрерывный текст типа:

> ффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффффф

то он растягивает таблицу и она выходит за пределы свой ширины. 
Ширину таблица наследует от `div`'a ,в самом `css width` задан в процентах. Жестко прописать ширину я не могу. Как тут можно поступить?
Обрезать слова тоже не всегда поможет так как в тексте если есть `html` теги, они будут обрезаться.

Comment: Смотря что Вы хотите. Видеть весь этот непрерывный текст или скрывать ( со скролом или без скрола или излишки убирать многоточием)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите в стилях соответствующего блока (ячейки) [`word-wrap:break-word`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)

Comment: Это не помогает просто потому что таблица подстраивается под содержимое. Тогда еще необходимо указать `table-layout: fixed` для таблицы. Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/uYcBY/3/

Но я бы сделал мягкий перенос — в том же примере есть скрипт, в котором нужно раскомментировать строку. Но этот вариант не прокатит, если в этой ячейке есть элементы с дочерними элементами, так что, я бы посоветовал бы использовать какой-то другой метод, который позволил бы работать отдельно с textNode-ами.

Comment: спасибо всем кто ответил ,помог способ 
word-wrap:break-word;
table-layout: fixed;

Пока все устраивает )

Comment: @Danis92, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом) :)